# Why throw makes function endpoint unreachable?

Tags: typescript

In `typescript` a use case of the type `never` is when a function has an unreachable endpoint. But I don't understand why the `throw` statement makes the function with an unreachable endpoint.

```js
function error(message: string): never {
    throw new Error(message);
}
```

Can somebody please explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `error` function never completes normally, because it *always* throws an error instead of completing normally:

```
function error(message: string): never {
    throw new Error(message); // <====== Terminates with an error here
                              // <====== Never gets here
}

error("foo");
// Execution never reaches this point
```

That means it never has a return value, hence the type `never` to annotate that fact.